# Creating a CloudWatch Metrics from the Athena Query results

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-athena

**My Requirement**

I want to create a **CloudWatch-Metric** from Athena query results.

**Example**

1. I want to create a metric like user_count of each day.
   In Athena, I will write an SQL query like this

```
select date,count(distinct user) as count from users_table group by 1
```

In the Athena editor I can see the result, but I want to see these results as a metric in Cloudwatch.

```
CloudWatch-Metric-Name ==> user_count
Dimensions ==> Date,count
```

If I have this cloudwatch metric and dimensions, I can easily create a **Monitoring Dashboard** and send **send alerts**

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/control-limits.html ?

Comment: I gone through these documents but these are helpful in monitoring queries like EXECUTED OR NOT OR SOMETHING RELATED TO PERFORMANCE.But I need to use the result of a the athena query and want to create metrics for that

Comment: Create a scheduled event to trigger lambda to execute Athena query then send the result as a metrics to CloudWatch

Comment: Hi Kane, if possible can you please send some sort of documents to get high level idea. So that i will proceed further

Comment: I worked with boto3 to [get query executions](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.batch_get_query_execution), storing the response in S3 and create a athena table on top of it again.

Comment: @PhilippJohannis , So can your result be surfaced on Dashboard?

Answer (score 3):

You can use CloudWatch [custom widgets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/add_custom_widget_dashboard.html), see "Run Amazon Athena queries" in [Samples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/add_custom_widget_samples.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's somewhat involved, but you can use a Lambda for this.  In a nutshell:

1. Setup your query in Athena and make sure it works using the Athena console.
2. Create a Lambda that:

   - Runs your Athena query
   - Pulls the query results from S3
   - Parses the query results
   - Sends the query results to CloudWatch as a metric
3. Use EventBridge to run your Lambda on a recurring basis

Here's an example Lambda function in Python that does step #2.  Note that the Lamda function will need IAM permissions to run queries in Athena, read the results from S3, and then put a metric into Cloudwatch.

```
import time
import boto3


query = 'select count(*) from mytable'
DATABASE = 'default'
bucket='BUCKET_NAME'
path='yourpath'


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    #Run query in Athena
    client = boto3.client('athena')
    output =  "s3://{}/{}".format(bucket,path)
    # Execution
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': DATABASE
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': output,
        }
    )

    #S3 file name uses the QueryExecutionId so 
    #grab it here so we can pull the S3 file.
    qeid = response["QueryExecutionId"]
    
    
    #occasionally the Athena hasn't written the file
    #before the lambda tries to pull it out of S3, so pause a few seconds
    #Note:  You are charged for time the lambda is running.
    #A more elegant but more complicated solution would try to get the 
    #file first then sleep.
    time.sleep(3)
    
    ###### Get query result from S3.
    s3 = boto3.client('s3');
    objectkey = path + "/" + qeid + ".csv"
    #load object as file
    file_content = s3.get_object(
        Bucket=bucket,
        Key=objectkey)["Body"].read()
    #split file on carriage returns
    lines = file_content.decode().splitlines()
    #get the second line in file
    count = lines[1]
    #remove double quotes
    count = count.replace("\"", "")
    #convert string to int since cloudwatch wants numeric for value
    count = int(count)
    
    
    #post query results as a CloudWatch metric
    cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
    response = cloudwatch.put_metric_data(
        MetricData = [
            {
                'MetricName': 'MyMetric',
                'Dimensions': [
                    {
                        'Name': 'DIM1',
                        'Value': 'dim1'
                    },
                ],
                'Unit': 'None',
                'Value': count
            },
        ],
        Namespace = 'MyMetricNS'
    )
    
    return response
    return
```

Comment: What if the result of the query is more than 1 line? For example, in the question, we need the info of unique users instead of the amount of unique users.

Comment: Adjust your query to return one line, or modify the Lambda to work with multiple results (i.e., multiple rows returned by the query) in the CSV file.