# Show Athena Queries Result on CloudWatch Dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-athena, facebook-insights

I have some tables in Athena Database that show the well-being of my system. I need to run the query every day to make sure nothing goes down. Is there a way to get it run on its own and show the results on CloudWatch Dashboard for my non-tech coworkers?

Comment: Similar to: [amazon web services - Creating a CloudWatch Metrics from the Athena Query results - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63715926/creating-a-cloudwatch-metrics-from-the-athena-query-results)

Comment: Added an answer to do this with a Lambda on question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63715926/creating-a-cloudwatch-metrics-from-the-athena-query-results since that question is older.